# e4crypt Operation not supported?

Tags: kernel, encryption

I am running Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 with 6.1.21+ kernel. I am trying to use [EXT4 encryption](https://askubuntu.com/a/646032/42850) with it, as such:

```bash
sudo tune2fs -O encrypt /dev/mmcblk0p3
sudo mount /dev/mmcblk0p3 /mnt
sudo mkdir /mnt/enc
salt="0x$(head -c 16 /dev/urandom | xxd -p)"
echo "my-password" | sudo e4crypt add_key -S "$salt" /mnt/enc
```

I'm getting following:

```
Enter passphrase (echo disabled): 
Added key with descriptor [a5010ebc4c804d30]
Error [Operation not supported] setting policy.
The key descriptor [a5010ebc4c804d30] may not match the existing encryption context for directory [/mnt/enc].
```

I believe this might be because of missing kernel support, but if that's the case, why? What's the point of including e2crypt utility with the distribution and not enabling support for it?